# Killing a chrome process by url name using python

Tags: python, google-chrome, python-os, psutil, python-webbrowser

I would like to run a python automation that will kill a particular chrome tab, by its url name.

For example:
if time is 09:00, and url is "www.youtube.com", kill this process.

I didn't manage to do it using `psutil`, with the following code, since I could only fetch process name (chrome.exe), and not each particular url name.

```
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        try:
            # Get process name & pid from process object.
            processName = proc.name()
            processID = proc.pid
            print(processName, ' ::: ', processID)
        except (psutil.NoSuchProcess, psutil.AccessDenied, psutil.ZombieProcess):
            pass
```

But the output would be as the following:
[image]

also, I tried some other python packages, such as `webbrowser` and `os`, but didn;t find one of them helpful.

I would like to add that while opening the task manager, it is possible to see all of the open tabs and their urls.

[image]

So, I would like to ask - do you know what's the easiet way to close a chrome tab by its url?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just found this [Python using Chrome Task manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54974396/python-chrome-task-manager-programmatically-access-chrome-task-managers-text)
recently while trying to implement a similar feature

I'm sure you'll get some ideas here.